# jQuery - get relative position and attribute of dropped elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I have draggable elements which can be dropped in droppable areas. If an element is dropped, the `drop` function is called:

```
$('#droppable').droppable({
    scope: "items",
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        // this one is called if an element is dropped in this droppable area
    }
});
```

My draggable element:

```
<div class="drag" data-noteid="10">Drag me</div>
...
$('.drag').draggable({
    revert: "invalid",
    scope: "items"
});
```

What I need to know if the element is dropped is the value of `data-noteid` and the relative position of the droppable area. So, if the element is dropped on the upper left corner, the x/y coordinates must be 0/0.

I created a full working example here: http://jsbin.com/utivo5/2/

So normally I can access the attributes like this:

```
alert($(this).data("noteid"));

alert($(this).position().top);
alert($(this).position().left);
```

but all I get in this case is `undefined`.

Do anyone know how I can access them? I think it must be possible with `event` or `ui` which is a parameter of the called `drop` function?!

Thank you in advance & Best Regards, Tim.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In this case you want the `ui` argument to get the draggable, rather than `this` which refers to the droppable area, specifically `ui.draggable` here.  It should look like this overall:

```
drop: function (event, ui) {
  var pos = ui.draggable.offset(), dPos = $(this).offset();
  alert("nodeid: " + ui.draggable.data("noteid") + 
        ", Top: " + (pos.top - dPos.top) + 
        ", Left: " + (pos.left - dPos.left));
}
```

For the position, we need to subtract the droppable's top/left position to get the value you want here, that's the `dPos` above getting removed.

[You can test your demo with the above changes working here](http://jsbin.com/utivo5/3).

Answer (score 4):

I found for my circumstances that the above didn't work. Not sure why - it always gave me an X = -7 and Y = 229.

But this did work (located in drop function handler):

```
alert('X pos in drop parent container = ' + (ui.position.top - $(this).offset().top));
```

Comment: Didnt work for me either, but that other answer only works for people with "simple" requirements :)